# How to assert a specific minimum Java version before running an ansible task?

Tags: ansible, openjdk

I would like to ensure Java is installed and the oldest acceptable version is 11.
How can I achieve that in ansible?

I have tried

```yml
- name: Fetch Java version
  shell: java -version 2>&1 | grep version | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/"//g'
  register: java_version

- assert:
    that:
      - java_version.stdout | version_compare('11', '>=')
```

Which does not work anymore because of the discontinued syntax in the `assert`.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can just replace `|` with `is` in the assert:

```yml
- name: Fetch Java version
  shell: java -version 2>&1 | grep version | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/"//g'
  register: java_version

- assert:
    that:
      - java_version.stdout is version_compare('11', '>=')
```